# How to match values in columns of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My goal is compare the values of column named ‘Total_studyPeriod’ of df2 with same name column in df3. Where the match is done on column value, I pick the corresponding row of df2 and df3 and write them in df4 and df5 so that I get two csv files of equal number of matched rows.

Below is my python code. I am using `isin` but I am not getting desired matching results, because both df2 and df3 do not have equal number of records. Suppose below are two dataframes, there should be two matching rows as output based on matching values, but I get three because 6.1 matches twice. I want it once for all same values.

Deleting the duplicates rows will not solve my problem because both files contain different values in other columns. Any idea that how I can get the desired results?

Please note that both dataframes do not have equal number of records.

```
DF2
Study_name  Total_studyPeriod(mon)  Total_Reporting_Duration(mon)   
A                     11.9            11.3  
B                     6.1             10.5  
C                     6.1             10.5  
D                     13.3            10.3  


DF3
Study_name  Total_studyPeriod(mon)  Total_Reporting_Duration(mon)   
X                     13.3            13
Y                     6.1             13    
Z                     8.4             12.2  

Output:

DF4
Study_name  Total_studyPeriod(mon)  Total_Reporting_Duration(mon)   
B                     6.1             10.5  
D                     13.3            10.3  


DF5
Study_name  Total_studyPeriod(mon)  Total_Reporting_Duration(mon)   
Y                     6.1             13    
X                     13.3            13
```

Here is my python code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(input_file)
df2 = df1[df1['Total_Reporting_Duration'] <= 12]
df2.to_csv('file1.csv')
df3=df1[(df1['Total_Reporting_Duration']>12)]
df3.to_csv('file2.csv')

cond =df2.loc[df2.Total_studyPeriod.isin(df3['Total_studyPeriod'])]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the final output to be. Could you include an example with fuller df's instead of just one column and show what the output should be?

Is it enough to just drop_duplicates on the Total_studyPeriod column?
`df2.loc[df2.Total_studyPeriod.isin(df3['Total_studyPeriod'])].drop_duplicates('Total_studyPeriod')`

Comment: Thank you very much @mitoRibo. Your solution worked but as I said I also want to write the output in df4 and df5. I did for df4 but do not know how I do in df5. For further clarity of what I want I have elaborated my question by adding more columns and showing desired output.

Comment: thank you for editing to make things more clear.

I'm still not sure exactly what you want though.
can you show what you did for df4 and what you tried for df5?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I fixed the `df5` order by using the `set_index` to alter the df index to be the `'Total_studyPeriod(mon)'` column and then indexed using the shared values.

This complicates the code because we have to reset the index afterwards, but I couldn't think of how better to do it, maybe someone else has a better answer!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Study_name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'},
    'Total_studyPeriod(mon)': {0: 11.9, 1: 6.1, 2: 6.1, 3: 13.3},
    'Total_Reporting_Duration(mon)': {0: 11.3, 1: 10.5, 2: 10.5, 3: 10.3},
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Study_name': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z'},
    'Total_studyPeriod(mon)': {0: 13.3, 1: 6.1, 2: 8.4},
    'Total_Reporting_Duration(mon)': {0: 13.0, 1: 13.0, 2: 12.2},
})

matches = np.intersect1d(df2['Total_studyPeriod(mon)'], df3['Total_studyPeriod(mon)'])

#Change the dfs to be indexed by the Total_studyPeriod column
df2 = df2.set_index('Total_studyPeriod(mon)')
df3 = df3.set_index('Total_studyPeriod(mon)')


df4 = df2.loc[matches].reset_index().drop_duplicates('Total_studyPeriod(mon)')

df5 = df3.loc[matches].reset_index().drop_duplicates('Total_studyPeriod(mon)')


print(df4)

print(df5)
```

Comment: Sure, I'll. In fact, it is first time that I am asking question on stack overflow. For df4, yes I did the same as you but for df5 I was confused.I highly appreciate your help and I have tried your code for df5 but yes the rows are out of order. I am trying to figure out the way to get them in the same order as in df4 based on matched value of 'Total_studyPeriod' .

Comment: @Rabi great first question then and welcome! I fixed the order in df5 with a different approach

Comment: Bundle of thanks @mitoRibo. However, when I applied the code on full dataset then I observed that duplicate removal method is creating issue in specific situation. In current scenario there are two similar values (6.1) in df2 but there is one in df3 means one matched pair and for second (6.1) in df2, there is no matching 6.1 in df4. For one for which there is no match we dropped it. If there are two 6.1 in df2 and two in df3, means two matched pair and should be selected but this code will still drop one. I am trying to fix this and may be the duplicate method is not the complete solution